# Polygon Neighbors not found in Proximity Toolset of ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing

I cannot find the Polygon Neighbors tool. I have searched for it as I usually do and I have also browsed the proximity toolset but it is not there. The other Tools, e.g. Buffer and Near are there and work fine.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? Sounds like you probably need to reinstall Arcmap if it truly is gone. Are there any other functions missing as well? (Please use the edit button below your question to update it)

Comment: I would employ model builder, iterate over polygons in A doing a select by location (sharing boundaries with B) and summarize. Will be slower but then it will achieve what you are after.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about this method please? I understand how to use model builder and the select by location tool, but not how to repeat 4000 times without doing manually.

Comment: Did you see this? http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/how-polygonneighbors-analysis-works.htm

Comment: Search the help file for (feature selection) iterators this will help you understand how to loop over the 4000 polygons in model builder.

Comment: Of cause it is *ALWAYS* worth a look at ArcScripts, here is [a 10.0 tool that finds adjacent features within a layer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=018c6d4b3c4849928cc973a5d2488bfa), not tried it so not sure if it can be automated. Probably not what you are after but I highly recommend this as a go to place for a possible tool created by one of the community users.

Comment: Spatial join one to many? Share boundary with or intersect

Comment: @FelixIP - that did exactly what was needed. Much more simple than I was expecting.

Comment: +1 I like when simple workarounds help to overcome such overly commercial licencing push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tool is available only since 10.1, you've indicated that you are on 10.0. ArcGIS 10.0 Help page is [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/#/An_overview_of_the_Proximity_toolset/000800000018000000/).

[image]

Your option is to upgrade to 10.1 or later or find 10.0 system and custom tools that could do a similar thing without using this 10.1 tool. I bet you can do this in ArcPy even in 10.0.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I will contact my workplace and ask for an Upgrade. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So it's actually very simple, as suggested by @FelixIP:

Spatial join one to many in ModelBuilder, then export the resulting table to excel and create a pivot table to summarise values of the B polygons.